# When does tableau/PowerBI load a dashboard tab/page into memory?

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

Let's say I share a Tableau or PowerBI dashboard with multiple tabs (or pages), and someone accesses that dashboard.

When someone loads the first tab, do all tabs (that need to be) load into memory, or are things only loaded into memory when that particular tab is accessed? In other words, if there are 3 tabs, and `tab1` takes up 10MB memory, `tab2` takes up 20MB memory, and `tab3` takes up 30MB memory. If a user loads a dashboard that 'stars' on tab1, does Tableau only load 10MB into memory for that tab (and load items incrementally with a loader if someone tries accessing another tab?)? Or, does it load all 60MB of memory at once (perhaps incrementally, prioritizing tab1) for the user so when they switch tabs they don't have to wait?

Here's an example from Power BI (multiple pages): https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Data-Stories-Gallery/Customer-Analysis-Dashboard/td-p/630893

[image]

And one with multiple tabs: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Data-Stories-Gallery/HR-Analytics-Dashboard/td-p/777914

[image]

And one for Tableau (tabs):

[image]

Comment: I don't know about Tableau but I'm pretty sure Power BI only loads the current view to memory (not the other pages).

Comment: @AlexisOlson thanks, can you point to a link in the docs or somewhere for this? Or how do you know that other than the loader? additionally, what happens when you 'leave' a tab -- does the memory for that tab clear or stay?

Comment: I haven't seen it in the docs (that I remember). I'm just inferring from experience since I know I have to wait sometimes when switching pages.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I see -- and then 'switching back' to a previous tab. How would that work?

Comment: It appears that the results get cached locally so that it can fetch them again without recomputing when switching back to a previous tab. Don't expect this cache to persist across users or for longer than an hour or so.

Comment: @AlexisOlson thanks for this -- let me know if you're able to find any docs regarding this!